# How to query nested arrays in a postgres json column?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, nested

I have some json similar to the json below stored in a postgres json column. I'm trying query it to identify some incorrectly entered data. I'm basically looking for addresses where the house description is the same as the house number. I can't quite work out how to do it.

```
{
  "timestamp": "2014-10-23T16:15:28+01:00",
  "schools": [
    {
    "school_id": "1",
    "addresses": [
      {
        "town": "Birmingham",
        "house_description": "1",
        "street_name": "Parklands",
        "addr_id": "4",
        "postcode": "B5 8KL",
        "house_no": "1",
        "address_type": "UK"
      },
      {
        "town": "Plymouth",
        "house_description": "Flat a",
        "street_name": "Fore Street",
        "addr_id": "2",
        "postcode": "PL9 8AY",
        "house_no": "15",
        "address_type": "UK"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "school_id": "2",
    "addresses": [
      {
        "town": "Coventry",
        "street_name": "Shipley Way",
        "addr_id": "19",
        "postcode": "CV8 3DL",
        "house_no": "662",
        "address_type": "UK"
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

I have written this sql which will find where the data matches:

```
select *
FROM title_register_data
where address_data->'schools'->0->'addresses'->0->>'house_description'= 
address_data->'schools'->0->'addresses'->0->>'house_no'
```

This obviously only works on the first address on the first school. Is there a way of querying all of the addresses of every school?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use `jsonb_array_elements()` in a lateral join as many times as the depth of a json array which elements you want to compare:

```
select 
    schools->>'school_id' school_id,
    addresses->>'addr_id' addr_id,
    addresses->>'house_description' house_description,
    addresses->>'house_no' house_no
from title_register_data,
jsonb_array_elements(address_data->'schools') schools,
jsonb_array_elements(schools->'addresses') addresses
where addresses->>'house_description' = addresses->>'house_no';

 school_id | addr_id | house_description | house_no 
-----------+---------+-------------------+----------
 1         | 4       | 1                 | 1
(1 row)
```

Comment: Excellent thank you. That is what I was after. I did tweak it slightly and used json_array_elements as it isn't a jsonb column but the principle is the same.

Comment: I would love to give you a double vote up, but that's not possible :)

Comment: This strips records whose schools array is empty (assuming no where clause). Do we have an elegant way to keep those records? (and keep the selected values as null?)

Comment: @fei0x - Use `left join ... on true`, see [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7878f8c88646f4498969eb52d5cb5a8b)

Comment: I can't say I totally understand why, but that definitely does the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Literally THANK YOU.