# How to speed up nested JSON query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql, performance, jsonb

For our development of a flight retail engine we store orders as JSON documents in a PostgreSQL database.

The order table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (
  id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  order_data  JSONB NOT NULL
);
```

A simplified version of a typical order document looks like this:

```
{  
   "orderID":"ORD000001",
   "invalid":false,
   "creationDate":"2017-11-19T15:49:53.897",
   "orderItems":[  
      {  
         "orderItemID":"ITEM000001",
         "flight":{  
            "id":"FL000001",
            "segments":[  
               {  
                  "origin":"FRA",
                  "destination":"LHR",
                  "departure":"2018-05-12T14:00:00",
                  "arrival":"2018-05-12T14:40:00",
                  "marketingCarrier":"LH",
                  "marketingFlightNumber":"LH908"
               }
            ]
         },
         "passenger":{  
            "lastName":"Test",
            "firstName":"Thomas",
            "passengerTypeCode":"ADT"
         }
      },
      {  
         "orderItemID":"ITEM000002",
         "flight":{  
            "id":"FL000002",
            "segments":[  
               {  
                  "origin":"LHR",
                  "destination":"FRA",
                  "departure":"2018-05-17T11:30:00",
                  "arrival":"2018-05-17T14:05:00",
                  "marketingCarrier":"LH",
                  "marketingFlightNumber":"LH905"
               }
            ]
         },
         "passenger":{  
            "lastName":"Test",
            "firstName":"Thomas",
            "passengerTypeCode":"ADT"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

The number of entries for this table can grow rather larger (up to over 100 million).

Creating a GIN index on "orderID" works fine and, as expected, significantly speeds up queries for orders with a specific ID.

But we also require a fast execution time for much more complex requests like searching for orders with a specific flight segment.

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075557/how-to-query-nested-arrays-in-a-postgres-json-column) thread I was able to write a request like

```
SELECT *
FROM orders,
  jsonb_array_elements(order_data->'orderItems') orderItems,
  jsonb_array_elements(orderItems->'flight'->'segments') segments
WHERE order_data->>'invalid'='false'
  AND segments->>'origin'='LHR'
  AND ( (segments->>'marketingCarrier'='LH' AND segments->>'marketingFlightNumber'='LH905') OR (segments->>'operatingCarrier'='LH' AND segments->>'operatingFlightNumber'='LH905') )
  AND segments->>'departure' BETWEEN '2018-05-17T10:00:00' AND '2018-05-17T18:00:00'
```

This works fine, but is too slow for our requirements.

What is the best way to speed up such a query?

Creating a materialized view like

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW order_segments AS
SELECT id, order_data->>'orderID' AS orderID, segments->>'origin' AS origin, segments->>'marketingCarrier' AS marketingCarrier, segments->>'marketingFlightNumber' AS marketingFlightNumber, segments->>'operatingCarrier' AS operatingCarrier, segments->>'operatingFlightNumber' AS operatingFlightNumber, segments->>'departure' AS departure
FROM orders,
  jsonb_array_elements(order_data -> 'orderItems') orderItems,
  jsonb_array_elements(orderItems -> 'flight'->'segments') segments
WHERE order_data->>'invalid'='false';
```

works, but has the disadvantage of not being updated automatically.

So, how would I define indices on the orders table to achieve fast execution times? Or is there an entirely different solution?

Comment: I don't know what your queries look iike in general, but have you considered indexing other columns as well? Like marketingCarrier and/or origin?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Yes, I have considered this, but unfortunately I never found out how to set proper indices on nested arrays within arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found an answer to my own question:

Setting an index

```
CREATE INDEX ix_order_items ON orders USING gin (((order_data->'orderItems')) jsonb_path_ops)
```

and using the request

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, order_data
FROM orders,
  jsonb_array_elements(order_data -> 'orderItems') orderItems,
  jsonb_array_elements(orderItems -> 'flight'->'segments') segments
WHERE id IN
( SELECT id
  FROM orders
  WHERE order_data->'orderItems'@>'[{"flight": {"segments": [{"origin":"LHR"}]}}]'
    AND (
      order_data->'orderItems'@>'[{"flight": {"segments": [{"marketingCarrier":"LH","marketingFlightNumber":"LH905"}]}}]'
      OR
      order_data->'orderItems'@>'[{"flight": {"segments": [{"operatingCarrier":"LH","operatingFlightNumber":"LH905"}]}}]'
    )
)
AND order_data@>'{"invalid": false}'
AND segments->>'departure' BETWEEN '2018-05-17T10:00:00' AND '2018-05-17T18:00:00'
```

speeds up the request from several seconds to a few milliseconds.