# How can I achieve mongo "unwind" in postgres JSONB? (Flatten nested arrays)

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, jsonb

I recently looked into migrating our product database from mongo to postgres. Coming from mongoDb, I am used of "unwinding" objects and arrays.

Suppose you have the following object:

```
{
  "styleGroupId": "2",
  "brand": "MOP",
  "colorVariants": [
    {
        "color": "red",
        "colorCode": "222",
        "sizeVariants": [
           {"gtin": "444",
           "size": "M"},
           {"gtin": "555",
           "size": "L"}
       ]
    },
    {
        "color": "blue",
        "colorCode": "111",
        "sizeVariants": [
           {"gtin": "66",
           "size": "M"},
           {"gtin": "77",
           "size": "L"}
       ]
    }
    ]
}
```

If you want to flatten it, in mongo you use the following:

```
db.test.aggregate([
{
    $unwind: "$colorVariants"
},
{
    $unwind: "$colorVariants.sizeVariants"
}
])
```

which will result in objects like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7dc59dafc86d25964b873c"),
    "styleGroupId" : "2",
    "brand" : "MOP",
    "colorVariants" : {
        "color" : "red",
        "colorCode" : "222",
        "sizeVariants" : {
            "gtin" : "444",
            "size" : "M"
        }
    }
}
```

I have spent hours searching for "mongo unwind in postgres" but could hardly find a satisfying answer. Also a lot of the resources on querying JSONB data in postgres barely touch nested arrays. Hopefully this post will help other poor souls searching for a migration from mongoDb to postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function:

```sql
create or replace function jsonb_unwind(target jsonb, path text[])
returns jsonb language plpgsql as $$
begin
    if jsonb_typeof(target #> path) = 'array' then
        return jsonb_set(target, path, target #> path -> 0);
    else
        return target;
    end if;
end $$;
```

Example usage:

```sql
select 
    jsonb_unwind(
        jsonb_unwind(json_data, '{colorVariants}'), 
        '{colorVariants, sizeVariants}')
from my_table;
```

[Test it in rextester.](http://rextester.com/ITEXD12027)

Answer (score 0):

The answer could implicitly found in this post: [How to query nested arrays in a postgres json column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075557/how-to-query-nested-arrays-in-a-postgres-json-column)

**edit**

paired with this answer [use - to remove a key from a JSONB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/select-columns-inside-json-agg/200240#200240)
there is an easier way to get sth closer to mongo unwind starting from 9.6

- You need to state each array level in the `FROM` clause of your query
- exclude each nested object from your output so it doesn't appear multiple times
- **optional** concatenate object and subobject

when concatenating objects with shared keys, only the key of the object right of the `||` operator will be preserved

-

```
SELECT
    data::jsonb - 'colorVariants' ||
    colorVariants.* - 'sizeVariants' || 
    sizeVariants.*
FROM
    test,
    jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'colorVariants') colorVariants,
    jsonb_array_elements(colorVariants -> 'sizeVariants') sizeVariants;
```

the result then is

```
                                                   ?column?
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"gtin": "11", "size": "M", "brand": "MOP", "color": "red", "colorCode": "222", "styleGroupId": "1"}
 {"gtin": "22", "size": "L", "brand": "MOP", "color": "red", "colorCode": "222", "styleGroupId": "1"}
 {"gtin": "33", "size": "M", "brand": "MOP", "color": "blue", "colorCode": "111", "styleGroupId": "1"}
 {"gtin": "44", "size": "L", "brand": "MOP", "color": "blue", "colorCode": "111", "styleGroupId": "1"}
 {"gtin": "444", "size": "M", "brand": "MOP", "color": "red", "colorCode": "222", "styleGroupId": "2"}
 {"gtin": "555", "size": "L", "brand": "MOP", "color": "red", "colorCode": "222", "styleGroupId": "2"}
 {"gtin": "66", "size": "M", "brand": "MOP", "color": "blue", "colorCode": "111", "styleGroupId": "2"}
 {"gtin": "77", "size": "L", "brand": "MOP", "color": "blue", "colorCode": "111", "styleGroupId": "2"}
```

---

**old post**

- You have to state each array level in the `FROM` clause of your query
- You have to specifically list the attributes of each level. If you only state e.g. `colorVariants` the nested arrays will also be returned

So in the specific case the solution would be:

```
SELECT 
    data->'brand' as brand, 
    data->'styleGroupId' as styleGroupId,
    colorVariants->'color' as color,
    colorVariants->'colorCode' as colorCode,
    sizeVariants->'gtin' as GTIN,
    sizeVariants->'size' as size
FROM 
    test,
    jsonb_array_elements(data->'colorVariants') colorVariants,
    jsonb_array_elements(colorVariants->'sizeVariants') sizeVariants
```

which will result in

```
 brand | stylegroupid | color  | colorcode | gtin  | size
-------+--------------+--------+-----------+-------+------
 "MOP" | "1"          | "red"  | "222"     | "11"  | "M"
 "MOP" | "1"          | "red"  | "222"     | "22"  | "L"
 "MOP" | "1"          | "blue" | "111"     | "33"  | "M"
 "MOP" | "1"          | "blue" | "111"     | "44"  | "L"
 "MOP" | "2"          | "red"  | "222"     | "444" | "M"
 "MOP" | "2"          | "red"  | "222"     | "555" | "L"
 "MOP" | "2"          | "blue" | "111"     | "66"  | "M"
 "MOP" | "2"          | "blue" | "111"     | "77"  | "L"
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple example.

Suppose you have the following data in  **userGroups** table

```
id | userId | groups
1  | 21     | [{"name": "group_1" }, { "name": "group_2" }]
```

if you query for attributes with  json_array_elements function for groups attribute

```sql
select id, userId, json_array_elements(groups) from userGroups;
```

you will get results similar to mongodb **unwind** operator results

```
id | userId | groups
1  | 21     | {"name": "group_1" }
1  | 21     | {"name": "group_2" }
```

Hope it helps someone!