# How to load Json data into multiple tables with normalized in Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I am having below format JSON data, I want to load into PostgreSQL table with normalized into multiple tables.

I have gone through below link 
[link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075557/how-to-query-nested-arrays-in-a-postgres-json-column.)

```
{
"Ref_1": "Value_1",
"Ref_2": "Value_2",
"Ref_7": {
    "Name_a": [
        {
            "Att1": "val_A1",
            "Att2": val_A2,
            "Att3": "val_A3"
        }
    ],
    "Name_e": [
        {
            "Att1": "val_E1",
            "Att2": {
                "Name_e_1": [
                    {
                        "Att_e_1": "val_E2",
                        "Att_e_2": val_E3,
                        "Att_e_3": "val_E4"
                    }
                ],
                "Name_e_2": [
                    {
                        "Att_e_1": "val_E8",
                        "Att_e_2": val_E9
                    }
                ],
                "Name_e_3": [
                    {
                        "Att_e_1": "val_E12",
                        "Att_e_2": val_E13
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Att3": val_E16,
            "Att4": "val_E17"
        }
    ],
"Ref_8": Value_7,
"Ref_9": Value_8
```

}

No Errors, I am looking for logic on implementation.

Comment: I have tried a few select statements, I am getting below error.                             
 ERROR:  cannot extract elements from an object
SQL state: 22023

Comment: Please show what you tried.